# get last entry for each date in timeseries dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column called `date_and_time`, and an associated `value` column. I would like to take the last entry for each date in the dataframe. Of course, groupby isn't very useful because there is no `df.groupby('date_and_time').last()` function.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
    date_and_time   value
07/01/2019 09:52    41998
07/01/2019 09:57    21183
07/01/2019 10:02    29730
07/01/2019 10:07    27855
07/01/2019 10:12    29359
08/01/2019 10:17    42057
08/01/2019 10:22    27307
08/01/2019 10:27    37205
08/01/2019 10:32    10969
08/01/2019 10:37    14085
09/01/2019 10:42    23218
09/01/2019 10:47    18972
09/01/2019 10:52    11286
09/01/2019 10:57    36341
09/01/2019 11:02    16913
10/01/2019 11:07    12131
10/01/2019 11:12    46921
10/01/2019 11:17    22412
10/01/2019 11:22    28503
10/01/2019 11:27    33918
```

and here is what I would like to have at the end:

```
date_and_time   value
07/01/2019 10:12    29359
08/01/2019 10:37    14085
09/01/2019 11:02    16913
10/01/2019 11:27    33918
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert first column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date_and_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_and_time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

If necessary sorting:

```
df = df.sort_values('date_and_time')
```

And then aggregate by [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df['date_and_time'].dt.date).last().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and inverting mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~df['date_and_time'].dt.date.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Last if need same format use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date_and_time'] = df['date_and_time'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

---

Solutions with no converting to datetimes - [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace and select first values - here `date`s:

```
df = df.groupby(df['date_and_time'].str.split().str[0]).last().reset_index(drop=True)

df = df[~df['date_and_time'].str.split().str[0].duplicated(keep='last')]
```